# Typehead in ng2-bootstrap cannot customise options to display different properties

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, ng2-bootstrap

When configuring ng2-bootstrap's [Typeahead-Grouping results](http://valor-software.github.io/ng2-bootstrap/#/typeahead#grouping-results), how to customise the options list to show as different properties?

In the documentation example:

```
<pre class="card card-block card-header">Model: {{groupSelected | json}}</pre>
<input [(ngModel)]="groupSelected"
       [typeahead]="statesComplex"
       typeaheadOptionField="name"
       typeaheadGroupField="region"
       class="form-control">
```

Typing `lan` would yield "Mayland"/South and "Rhode Island"/NorthEast.

If I have an additional property `title` like so:

```
{id: 21, name: 'Maryland', region: 'South', title: 'The Beautiful'},
{id: 40, name: 'Rhode Island', region: 'Northeast', title: 'The Amazing'},
```

How to customise the template to list `The Beautiful` and `The Amazing` instead? I've tried `optionsListTemplate` and `typeaheadItemTemplate` in various permutations with `{{groupSelected | json}}` but to no avail.

Comment: I'd posted a partial answer. Answers that show usage of `typeaheadItemTemplate` in tandem with `optionsListTemplate` will be marked as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Use `typeaheadItemTemplate`.

At the `input` tag, add `typeaheadItemTemplate` like so:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="groupSelected"
  ...
  [typeaheadItemTemplate]="myItemTemplate"
>
```

Then add an accompanying `template` tag like so:

```
<template #myItemTemplate let-model="item">
  {{model.title | json}}
</template>
```

Extra notes:

- `myItemTemplate` is any arbitrary value to bind the input element with your custom template tag.
- `item` is your collection (array of objects)
- `let-model` iterates through your collection.
- `model.title` displays the desired property (using `title` as an example).